# Changing LUMA Logo

Tags: magento-2.1, logo

To change the theme i found this solution
Go to your Magento 2 admin.
Go to STORES > Configuration > Design > Header.
Click Choose file and select your logo.
Click Save Config.

But Design tab Header is not showing to me
Can somebody help me.
Magento 2.1.2 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to Content>Design>Configuration and Edit your store and go to Header Menu.

[image]

Thanks I hope it helped you.

Comment: You're welcome @sandeep you should accept my answer or upvote so that others can use this as reference in the future :)

Comment: I am graduate student from Arkansas University
I have been given a project to design a E Commerce Website

I have designed a website using Magento 2.1.2 with the help of YouTube videos
Its working fine with the help of local host 
I need to submit my project as executable file to my professor

Can you help me how can i make it executable in my professor laptop
As the server is in my system How can it work in other systems


Thank You

Comment: Of course no problem.

Comment: Hi @sandeep what operating system are you using in your computer?

Comment: Windows 10 @MazeStrics

Comment: If you're using windows open command prompt and type ipconfig. go to your database and look for table name core_config_data change the base url and secure url for example my IP is 192.168.1.1. Then you should change the base url and secure url to  https://192.168.1.1/magento/ so that it can be accessed by your professor. If you need clarification just feel free to ask :)

Comment: Are you using XAMPP? or WAMPP?

Comment: Before that i want to change my url
now it is opening with the default url Localhost/magento
am using XAMPP
and i really appreciate ur help

Comment: Yes you can change that in your database with the screenshot I provided below.

Comment: SO i have to give my professor IP address there to make it work in his laptop rite?

Comment: Yes exactly! for example I changed my url using my IP. 

10.0.1.107/m2ten/ <---This should be the URL that you will give to your professor. You can change it whatever IP you're computer is assigned to

Comment: can i use any url like https://buyme.com

Comment: Please refer to this link: http://www.complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name

If you want to use that url over local area network, but just try that one

Comment: I have changed ip address to my friend laptop ip address
and now in my friend laptop how can i open it?

Comment: You should only use your own "IP adress" Not your friend's IP address.

I mean if your server is your own laptop then you should use your laptop's IP address. Not other Ip address

Comment: but i want to make it executable in other laptop
coz i have to send it to my professor

Comment: For example in my laptop. I have 192.168.1.1/magento then in order for the site to be opened in another computer like your friend's laptop. you should use the url 192.168.1.1/magento into your friends browser.

Comment: Yes I understand what you meant with. In order for your friend to access your site. give him your IP address for example like this format 192.168.1.1/magento <--- Note that magento is your directory of your site you can change it to the way you wanted it to be

Comment: As you said I cahnged it to my ipaddess as http://10.0.0.24/magento/
so will this url work in any syatem

Comment: Take note also: You should be connected in one network in order for your friend to access your IP address url.

Comment: Yes it will work as long as you are connected in the same network,

Comment: Yeah i just checked it, Its working in my friend laptop
but as it is an assignment I have to submit a report and detailed notes of how to make my project work in his laptop
At that time we will not be connected in the same netwok,coz i will submit it in blackboard university portal
So how can i make it work?

Comment: @sandeep in that matter I think you will need to host your project in a hosting provider so that your professor or instructor can access it as long as he is connected on the internet. 

These are some hosting sites you may want to use:

https://www.siteground.com/
https://www.godaddy.com/

But you can explore there are lots of free hosting sites out there in the internet.

Comment: If i buy any doamin and update it in core_config_data table with that domain
will it work in any system irrespective of network?

Comment: Yes it will work but its a long process in order for that to work if you want that your laptop is the server.

Comment: You can refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845562/pointing-domain-name-to-server-ip-running-xampp-and-wordpress

Credits for the author of that link and the contributors

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database of your magento installation and look for the table name core_config_data and change the base url and secure url

[image]

Comment: Hello sir are you available now?

Comment: Hello I'm now available, Sorry I got busy earlier

Answer (score 0):

That folder must be the folder of your project or magento installation. under xampp/htdocs/magento

[image]